# Autocomplete using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

can someone recommand a good autocomplete or autosuggest that uses javascript or jquery?
I want it to be fast and with no ajax.

Thanks.

Comment: Interestingly HTML5 provides a "local autocomplete" facility using the <datalist> element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [jQuery Autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete) allows you to use either Ajax *OR* a locally-defined data set (no ajax).

Answer (score 0):

It's best to Use the jquery UI built in Autocomplete Widget. http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

The good part is, all jquery scripts can be loaded from google CDN. No extra load on your server.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```