# Issue in reloading of names while live search using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, search

so I was trying to make a simple search option whereas the user types in the name, the name shows up. However, with my code, the name shows up only when the user completely types the name right. Basically, I want it to show all available names relevant to user's search (If user

```js
 const li = document.querySelectorAll("li");
    const input = document.querySelector("#search");
    const form = document.querySelector("form");
    const searchBtn = document.querySelector("button");
    const loopThrough = () => {
     for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      if (input.value.toLowerCase() === li[i].innerText.toLowerCase()) {
       li[i].style.display = "block";
      }
      if (li[i].style.display = "block" && input.value.toLowerCase().length == 0) {
       li[i].style.display = "none";
      }
     }
    }
    input.addEventListener("keyup", loopThrough);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search here...">
  <button type="button">Search</button>
</form>
 <ul>
  <li>Pierre</li>
  <li>Peter</li>
  <li>Philip</li>
  <li>Mazen</li>
  <li>Zeina</li>
  <li>Anna</li>
  <li>Wael</li>
  <li>Fadi</li>
  <li>Faris</li>
  <li>Walid</li>
 </ul>
```

types "p", I want all names that start with "p" to show up.)
and initially, in CSS, all li display property is set to none

Comment: You could look into https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autocomplete using jquery or javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982933/autocomplete-using-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: well, you're comparing the whole value (`input.value === li.innertext` …), so of course it shows only when the word matches completely

Comment: @Adam, yes it possible with JQuery, but I have not learned it yet!! any pure JavaScript help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You directly comparing values and if u want to show similar ones then use RegExp

Comment: Maybe chekck HTML5 <datalist> for casual input. https://caniuse.com/#feat=datalist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a trivial thing to do with JavaScript and a document like you have. Some pointers:

- Forget "keyup", and in fact all explicit keyboard events. You are doing yourself and your users disservice. Not all devices have keyboards, and smart people behind Web standards have long ago foreseen this and there are "input" and "change" events available to fire on every text input control.
- You can initiate a search on every "input" or "change" event, but if your search queries take any time at all, you would be wise to reset a search *timeout* on every "input" event at least instead -- some people type very fast, and there is no good need on application's part to run a search query for every letter typed -- that would be well over 10 searches a second in many cases for fast typers. Waste of resources -- reset a timeout so that a search is queued after half a second or so. The number should typically be user's preference, but it's a minute preference that most people won't bother with, so just use some good enough average.
- Don't use inline styles in this case. They very seldom are a fitting part of a solution. Use CSS classes, so that behavior and style of the elements that match your search, can be specified in the stylesheet. Or you can use the `hidden` attribute, it may be suitable, depending.

Here is some off-the-top-of-my-head code that solves your problem, adapted from your snippet:

```
var timeout;
document.getElementById("form").elements.search.addEventListener("input", function(ev) {
    if(timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function(input) {
        for(const li of document.querySelectorAll("li")) {
            li.classList.toggle("match", li.textContent.startsWith(input.value));
        }
    }, 500, ev.target);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `startsWith` function

With your code:

```
const li = document.querySelectorAll("li");
const input = document.querySelector("#search");
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const searchBtn = document.querySelector("button");
const loopThrough = () => {
for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        if (input.value.toLowerCase().startsWith(li[i].innerText.toLowerCase())) {
            li[i].style.display = "block";
        }
        if (li[i].style.display = "block" && input.value.toLowerCase().length == 0) {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
input.addEventListener("keyup", loopThrough);
```

Comment: It produced the same results, the name shows up when the user types the whole name and not when the user types in the first few letters